# Fast-RCNN final bounding box

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I've been playing around with Fast-RCNN for a while, but still can't get some of the core mechanisms.

In the tutorial slides (page 28 of http://tutorial.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/caffe-cvpr15-detection.pdf), they have an example output with only one bounding box per object:

http://s22.postimg.org/7rbu05xbl/Screen_Shot_2015_12_04_at_2_19_57_PM.png

Specifically, non-maximum suppression is performed on all region proposals(https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn/blob/master/lib/fast_rcnn/test.py#L324), but in my case it still contains tens of regions for each object in the image.

My bounding boxes look like the following with threshold of 0.99:

http://s29.postimg.org/oc33ujgrb/foo.jpg

How and where are the bounding boxes for overlapping region finalized into one?

Comment: can please you post an image that exemplifies what you're trying to explain?

Comment: @carlosdc I somehow thought that bounding boxes are finalized into a few, but it may have been incorrect. Does fast-rcnn simply return the score, which should be dealt with by the user as they like?

Comment: @carlosdc for example, on page 28 of http://tutorial.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/caffe-cvpr15-detection.pdf, it seems like bounding boxes are finalized?

Comment: yes, they are, that is what non max suppression does.

Comment: @carlosdc but in my case, there are tens of boxes around, say, one same car that are highly overlapping. How does it finalize one most fitting bounding box per object?

Comment: @carlosdc for example, this is what I get with threshold of 0.99 http://s29.postimg.org/oc33ujgrb/foo.jpg

Comment: @ytrewq, I have exactly the same problem when training a faster rcnn over a person dataset. Did you find a solution to your problem yet?

Comment: @Tanvir why not simply average the coordinates for the four corners for all of the returned boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Non-maximum supression should definitely filter out the overlapping bounding boxes in you example image.
Check again that you use it properly, and do it after fine-tuning the initial bounding box using the network output.

Answer (score 0):

Non-maximum suppression rejects overlap regions larger than the threshold. As your threshold is 0.99, few overlap regions will be rejected.